# How to use child router using ngrx/router?

Tags: typescript, angular, router, ngrx

When I use deprecated router for **child router**, I use like this:

**Parent router:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [RouterOutlet],
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/landing/...', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent }
])
```

---

**Child router:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'landing-component',
  directives: [RouterOutlet],
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>      
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/welcome', name: 'Welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
])
export class LandingComponent {
}
```

I am trying to switch to ngrx/router. How can I do it correctly using ngrx/router?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use it now:

```
const landingRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '/landing1', component: Landing1Component },
  { path: '/landing2', component: Landing2Component }
];

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/landing',
    component: LandingComponent,
    index: {
      component: WelcomeComponent
    },
    loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(landingRoutes))
  }
];
```

Make sure you return `promise` inside of `loadChildren`.

If you want to do Code Splitting with Asynchronous Routes, check [here](https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/docs/overview/code-splitting.md) for more details.